# DIV or table to achieve this?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to add 4 colored-rectangles at the bottom of my blue DIV (width is dynamic) but I'm hesitating on the approach to take before starting coding. Should I use a table approach with 4 columns 25% each, or a DIV approach with 4 DIV next to each other? Thanks

[image: What I have]

[image: What I'd like to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I see no need for a table there. I'd use 4 divs, float'ed left with the correct width.